# Placing an RLC input filter at the input of a buck

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, buck, stability, passive-filter

Since bucks have current spikes at the input side, it's best to use an input filter as you get better noise reduction than using an output filter (afaik).

Using a regulator IC however, that is, one you don't know about the transfer function as the IC is like a black box somewhat, I wonder how would somebody design a filter for it and still meet correct stability.

I'd like to place a RLC 2nd order (flat butterworth response with cutoff around 4kHz) using the [AOZ1284PI IC](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1284PI.pdf)

This is to step down 5V to 4V.

My question basically is... how can I insure the buck will be stable with this input filter? Should I worry or are most bucks "stable enough" to support an input filter?

Thanks

Comment: A *second-order Butterworth response* assumes linear source & load. A buck is not a linear load.

Answer (score 1):

First, the filters have two different purposes, unless this were a true two-wire device, and the AOZ1284 is *not*.

- An input filter

  - provides a smoothed voltage source to the buck converter.
  - and it prevents high-frequency harmonics (RF noise) from getting into the *supply* line.
- An output filter eliminates ripple and noise from the *output* line.

Second, the product description already includes C<sub>in</sub> on the schematic; additional series inductance of the filter would be fine, though it would be a good idea to **increase the value of C<sub>in</sub>**, which must come *after* the filter, and use both large electrolytic and small ceramic caps to insure a low-impedance supply to the IC.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a high impedance low frequency Pole will degrade load regulation and add a high Q resonance at the pole frequency under low load conditions as the filter becomes underdamped.

Load regulation from a Step load is defined by the ratio of source to load impedance divided by the loop gain spectrum. This shows up as overshoot and ripple spectrum. So very low f and high f is corrected to some extent but is worst at resonant frequency, fo=4kHz which can be stimulated by load spectrum.

### Conclusion on source impedance.

You want a very low source impedance with a breakpoint above the switching frequency. Use Low ESR source bulk Caps in the single-digit microsecond ESR*C =Tau range across a low Zo voltage source.